# wpa_supplicant - run without sudo

Tags: wpa-supplicant

I'm developing an embedded linux application & it uses [egt](https://github.com/linux4sam/egt) as the GUI front-end. The GUI uses wpa_supplicant to connect/ register WiFi network. I've got the same GUI application running on my desktop for development purposes.

Accessing wpa_supplicant (e.g. wpa_ctrl_open) isn't an issue on the actual embedded device as it runs as root, but on the desktop I'm running into permission errors. I don't want to run the GUI application as root on my desktop in case it trashes my system.

So whats the proper way to run wpa_supplicant as non-root?

Many thanks,

Comment: https://w1.fi/wpa_supplicant/devel/ctrl_iface_page.html and set the permissions for the UNIX socket properly.

Comment: Thanks for the input. Are you referring to ctrl_path in `struct wpa_ctrl * wpa_ctrl_open(const char *ctrl_path)`, i.e. the WiFi interface in var/run/supplicant? I've tried changing this to my user ID/ group but still getting NULL on return

Answer (score 0):

All credit goes to [Klaus D.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3929826/klaus-d) for the correct answer. As he suggested the issue as the permissions on the sockets. Initially I only changed the permission of the actual socket (i.e. WiFi interface) but the actual containing folder needs to be set correctly also (i.e. var/run/supplicant).

Thanks Klaus & hope this helps someone else.